# Do I need JBossWS for EJB3 Webservices?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, use-case

We have Web services developed using EJB3, Hibernate, Jboss AS, JAX-WS, etc.

When going through Webservices and deployment, I see JBossWS references.

Do I really need it for my Webservices to work? Or optional?
What are the use cases for JBossWS?

If JBossWS is not needed and JBossAS is enough, how do I see my web services from JBoss AS, web console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss WS is the implementation of JAX-WS standard which is provided together with JBoss AS. JBoss WS is developed by Red Hat, so it is "native" implementation for JBoss (for JBoss 5.X and JBoss 6.x series).

So yes, you need JBossWS for web services to work. But...

But in case of JBoss 5.X.GA JBoss WS can be replaced by Apache CXF or Metro implementations of JAX-WS. Anyway, you need some JAX-WS implementation.

In case of the newest JBoss version - 7.X, JBossWS is abandoned and Apache CXF is used.

There is also jbossws Web application (available on local machine at localhost:8080/jbossws) - this application is not needed for webservices to work, but it is convienient for downloading WSDL files or checking if web service was deployed - it can be password protected, if needed.

Comment: So in JBoss 4.x, JBossWS is embedded by default?

Comment: Yes, in \server\default\deploy\jbossws.sar service archive. In JBoss 4.X it is "fixed", As far as I can remember you cannot replace it with any other alternative.